# Leaflet :: Changing icon based on zoom level

Tags: javascript, leaflet

How do I go about changing an icon height & width based on Leaflet zoom level?

I'm using Leaflet api v0.7.5

Comment: Stackoverflow encourages to try it on your own first and post code if it does not work.

Comment: I think on each zoom level you can replace marker with different height and width

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=change+icon+zoom+level+leaflet&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `L.Marker.setIcon` method together with the map's `zoomend` event, i.e.:

```
var marker = L.marker(…).addTo(map);
var bigIcon = L.icon(…);
var smallIcon = L.icon(…);

map.on('zoomend', function(ev){
  if (map.getZoom() > 16) {
    marker.setIcon(bigIcon);
  } else {
    marker.setIcon(smallIcon);
  }
})
```

Also, note that Leaflet 0.7.5 is deprecated. You are encouraged to switch to 1.0.0-rc3 (which is the latest available at the time of this writing).